# Place many controls in a rectangle like frame in androd studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

I have two Edit text boxes and two spinners in my app.
For a attractive design of app, I want to place these controls in a rectangle with a solid color.(Like the use of ***frame control*** in vb6)
I have placed a view as below but no result
Please suggest a solution

code of view in my app

```
<view
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    style="@style/AppTheme"

    class="android.support.constraint.Placeholder"
    android:layout_width="367dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bordertext"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Add android tags to make it more visible

Comment: Thank you.Added tags; Please suggest the solutions

Comment: Can you please post an image (or drawing) of what it looks like, and what it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use drawable shape as per your requirement like below

First of all, create a new XML file inside the drawable folder, and add the above code, then save it as `rectangle_shape.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

Then in a `layout` file

you can use above shape like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works .Now the problem is that all the controls are hidden by the layout .

Comment: hidden by the layout means? share your update code and screenshot

Answer (score 0):

my code is below

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
 </item>
<item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp"  android:top="5dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
  </item>
 </layer-list>






<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="113dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:visibility="visible"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinmain"
    android:layout_width="352dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="416dp"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view7" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

The spinner is not visible by the rectangle.I want to display the spinner inside the rectangle.